# C++ using global variable shows 100% slower than a pointer, when using pthread?

Tags: c++, linux, performance, variables, pthreads

I've got a quite program to show the performance of 2 similar programs, both uses 2 threads to do calculation. The core difference is that one uses a global variable, another uses a "new" object, as below:

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct M{
    long a;
    long b;
}obj;
size_t count=2000000000;
void* addx(void*args){
    long*pl=(long*)args;
    for(size_t i=0;i<count;++i)
        (*pl)*=i;
    return NULL;
}
int main(int argc,char*argv[]){
    pthread_t tid[2];
    pthread_create(&tid[0],NULL,addx,&obj.a);
    pthread_create(&tid[1],NULL,addx,&obj.b);
    pthread_join(tid[0],NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[1],NULL);
    return 0;
}

clang++ test03_threads.cpp -o test03_threads -lpthread -O2 && time ./test03_threads

real    0m3.626s
user    0m6.595s
sys 0m0.009s
```

It's quite slow, then I modified obj to be dynamically created(I expected it to be even slower):

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct M{
    long a;
    long b;
}*obj;//difference 1
size_t count=2000000000;
void* addx(void*args){
    long*pl=(long*)args;
    for(size_t i=0;i<count;++i)
        (*pl)*=i;
    return NULL;
}
int main(int argc,char*argv[]){
    obj=new M;//difference 2
    pthread_t tid[2];
    pthread_create(&tid[0],NULL,addx,&obj->a);//difference 3
    pthread_create(&tid[1],NULL,addx,&obj->b);//difference 4
    pthread_join(tid[0],NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[1],NULL);
    delete obj;//difference 5
    return 0;
}

clang++ test03_threads_new.cpp -o test03_threads_new -lpthread -O2 && time ./test03_threads_new

real    0m1.880s
user    0m3.745s
sys 0m0.007s
```

It's amazingly 100% faster than the previous one. I also tried g++ on linux, same result.
But how to explain this? I know obj is global variable, but *obj is still global variable, just dynamically created. What's the core difference?

Comment: Not able to reproduce [test1](http://ideone.com/jDOQ0b) (3.54s) and [test2](http://ideone.com/C9R9ja) (3.55s). Also shouldn't `-O2` be placed before .cpp path?

Comment: Might have something to do with false sharing, but one would expect false sharing to be an issue in both implementations.

Comment: Are your executables 32- or 64-bit?

Comment: Sorry, but what's a false sharing? I tested on both my mac and linux, the result is stable.

Comment: @Troskyvs : When 2 threads are working on objects that sit in the same cache line, each access by one thread will invalidate the cache line for the other thread, forcing a reload from higher up cache/main memory which is expensive. ( https://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.be/2011/07/false-sharing.html )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this is indeed because of false sharing, as Unimportant suggested.

Why the difference then, you may ask?

Because of the `count` variable! As this is a **variable**, and `size_t`'s underlying type happens to be `long` for you, the compiler cannot optimize it away (because `pl` could point to `count`). If `count` would be an `int`, because of strict aliasing rules, the compiler can optimize it away (or simply it could be `const size_t`).

So the generated code has to read `count` every time in the loop.

In the first example, `count` and `obj` both global variables, they are placed near to each other. So, there is a high possibility that the linker put these variables into the same cache line. So writing to `obj.a` or `obj.b` will invalidate the cache line of `count`. **So the CPU has to synchronize the reads of `count`.**

In the second example, `obj` is allocated on the heap, it's address will be far enough from `count`, so they won't occupy the same cache line. **No synchronization needed for `count`**.